# Badly behaved, but easy-to-manipulate examples of rings to test hypotheses on

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

In calculating examples in mathematics it's often useful to have a quite misbehaving but easy-to-manipulate object to test hypotheses on. Examples are the function  $ f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x \in \Bbb{Q}\\ 
 1& \text{ if } x\not \in \Bbb{Q} 
\end{cases}$ in analysis, or the Baumslag-Solitar groups $B(n,m)$ in group theory.

***Do there exist rings that are like this?*** If so, which are your favourites?

At the moment I tend to use $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/d \Bbb{Z}$, which is really sub-optimal: it is nearly impossible to tell whether a property one finds is specific to the ring I'm using or not. I especially find this troublesome when investigating properties of ideals.

Comment: *Boolean rings* are very interesting.

Comment: @N.H. Oh, thanks! Maybe you could answer with an example if you have the time?

Comment: There is more informations about these rings on this blog https://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/boolean-rings-ultrafilters-and-stones-representation-theorem/
Else, I think other people will probably gives you better examples than mine ;)

Comment: @Alyosha I changed the title to something more specific. If your question really was "what are your favorite rings" it would be quickly closed as off-topic. But I think your idea of gathering useful pathological examples has some merit.

Comment: @Alyosha If you'd like to browse some examples (some of them probably don't qualify as easy-to-manipulate), you might be interested in [ths site](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some example from complex analysis.

The ring of holomorphic function $\mathcal O(\mathbb C)$ has lot of interesting properties, for example it is a Bezout ring but not a PID.

Another examples are here, can you try to find the noetherian one ? (this is an exercise in Atiyah and Mcdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*)

- The rational functions with no poles on the circle $|z|=1$
- The power series with a positive radius of convergence
- The power serie with an infinite radius of convergence
- The polynomials in $z$ with first $k$ derivatives which vanishes at $z=0$
- The ring of polynomial in $z,w$ which first $k$ derivatives with respect to $w$ vanishes for $z=0$.

If you want to find many examples of rings, you can look in algebraic geometry or number theory where rings and ideals arise in a very natural way.